# Connect to Amazon ec2 Instance without specifying .pem file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been using the following command to connect to my amazon ec2 instance from my OSX terminal:

```
ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

So I need to include the .pem file location on the command.

Is there any way, so that I do not need to specify the .pem file each time i connect?

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, i have got the solution. Here I am sharing if someone need sometimes:

- Copy the `.pem` file to `~/.ssh`
- Create a config file at `~/.ssh`

  `touch ~/.ssh/config`
- open the config file in nano or vim. `nano ~/.ssh/config`
- Add the following line to `config` file

  `Host host_name`

  `HostName ec2.server.address.com`

  `User ec2-user`

  `IdentityFile "~/.ssh/ec2.pem"`
- Now connect from terminal: `ssh host_name`

Answer (score 1):

Use **ssh-add** command to add your .pem file

Then you do not have to specify the pem files in the ssh command line. What it does is adds one or more pem file to the ssh-agent which is supplied during ssh connection.

**ssh-add -l** will list all pem file the agent knows.

If ssh-add complains the agent is not running, start the agent by calling
eval `ssh-agent -s`

For more indo, do man on **ssh-agent** and **ssh-add**

Answer (score 0):

Mohammad -

You can set a default identity file for SSH on your user profile. Simply copy that pem file to ./ssh/id_rsa or ~/.ssh/id_dsa (depending on the format). I pulled this from the SSH man page, link to source below.

> -i identity_file
>
> Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for RSA or DSA authentication is read. The default is ~/.ssh/identity
>   for protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_dsa for
>   protocol version 2. Identity files may also be specified on a per-host
>   basis in the configuration file. It is possible to have multiple -i
>   options (and multiple identities specified in configuration files).

http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh

Answer (score 0):

Since [aws cli version 2.12.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-cli/v2/CHANGELOG.rst) there is the [ec2-instance-connect ssh](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2-instance-connect/ssh.html) option:

> - feature:`ec2-instance-connect`: Add `ssh` and `open-tunnel` commands for connecting to an EC2 instance via an OpenSSH client and a websocket tunnel respectively.

So you can do the following:

```
aws ec2-instance-connect ssh --instance-id "$BASTION_INSTANCE_ID"
```